# Graphical Programming with WebGUI

Tags: gpio, web-server

I was wondering if there is any project that enables a user to write some simple [IFTTT](https://ifttt.com/) style programs for the Pi (or other Linux boards) that also breaks out the GPIOs of the Pi to be used in such a program.

So someone with some basic knowledge about electronics but with very little to no programming knowledge could do some simple programs like "if time is 6 pm make gpio 3 high" in a web gui. Pretty much like IFTTT but local and maybe with a little more features to make some more complex logic than just "if this than that".

Comment: I'haven't used it myself, but look into Scratch.  I think there's a plugin for it that allows you to control GPIO as described here: http://computers.tutsplus.com/tutorials/learn-how-to-use-raspberry-pi-gpio-pins-with-scratch--mac-59941

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scratch GPIO is a great way to control the pins using a GUI: http://cymplecy.wordpress.com/2013/04/22/scratch-gpio-version-2-introduction-for-beginners/

I've also found this: http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=37&t=50246